# React.js design pattern: save editable document with multiple fields from the *parent* node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a WYSIWYG editor on the client side, with a toplevel `NewProjectContainer` render function that is:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className="blog-post">
            <TitleContainer   user={this.props.user}/>
            <ContentContainer user={this.props.user}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Both the `TitleContainer` and `ContentContainer` can be edited, and should be saved to both local storage, and when unmounted, save to backend db. Currently each component has its own `saveLocal` and `saveDb` function which is clearly an antipattern. Ideally the child nodes should hand over their content to the parent node `NewProjectContainer`, which then should handle the save logic. Does React agree this is the "sane" way to do things? if so are there language constructs (i'm new here) in React that facilitate this?  The simplest way is to pass a function down as props, but this smells weird, am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the pitfalls you want to avoid is to have your state spread out throughout your app.

Here is what I suggest:

- Start by having the entire app state inside `NewProjectContainer` and passing down functions and properties as props. Ideally `TitleContainer` and `ContentContainer` would be *pure components* meaning that they don't have their own react state (`this.state`). You would then separate all the API calls and business logic inside your parent container and use the children for display only.
- Once your app grows beyond 3 components, you might want to look at a state management solution. The most popular are [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction) and [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx). There are plenty of tutorials online on how to get started with these. These libraries will help you structure the way you handle state and side effects (API calls and other async operations)